# Blender 4 keeps lagging for no reason

Tags: texturing, cloth-simulation

Ever since I downloaded Blender 4 it has been lagging so much(especially when I use physics simulations),
whenever a project is starting to be a little complex blender starts operating at a very low FPS and it becomes unworkable.
The reason can't be my PC because 3.5 worked perfectly.

My PC has:
12th Gen Intel Core i7-12700F 2.10 GHz
16 GB of RAM
GTX 1650
Windows 10 Home

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: pls share your file at blend-exchange